# Neighborhood by Zip Codes for New York and Los Angeles

Tags: data-request, usa

I haven't been able to find an online open source of US neighborhoods with their corresponding zip codes. I am particularly looking for New York and Los Angeles.

Comment: Please define *US neighborhoods*.

Comment: I think that's part of the problem, so for example in New York: Upper East Side, Upper West Side, Midtown, Lower East Side, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use/combine [Code for America's Click That 'hood](http://click-that-hood.com/) with [Zillow Neighborhood Boundary Shapefiles](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm) to get some, if not all of that data. Data is here:

[Click That 'hood Data Directory](https://github.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/tree/master/public/data)
[California Neighborhood Boundaries](https://www.zillowstatic.com/static/shp/ZillowNeighborhoods-CA.zip)
[New York Neighborhood Boundaries](https://www.zillowstatic.com/static/shp/ZillowNeighborhoods-NY.zip)